# How to get details of user who Pushed an Image in to Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure-container-registry, acr

Is there a way to get details of Users who pushed an Image in to Azure Container Registry (ACR). We have enabled RBAC and integrated the ACR with Azure Active Directory. When I go to a repository and see the details of Image, it currently does not show information like who pushed the image to ACR.

Comment: Does the solution solve your problem? Or you need more help? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the ACR does not store the people who pushed the images. You can only see the messages that when you create the repository and when you update it. You can use the CLI command `az acr repository show --repository repo_name` and it's output like this:

[image]

ACR does not care about who pushes the images, if someone has the permission, then he can do it. The ACR is a private docker registry, so I recommend that it's better for you to control the permissions of the ACR then record the messages who pushed the images. You can control the permissions following the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles).

Comment: @Manu I'm happy to hear that the answer is helpful to you :-)

Comment: Also while going through the list of feedback provided for ACR, I saw that the Audit trial for any image operation in ACR is being developed. Link : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/903958-azure-container-registry/suggestions/34222399-expose-acr-audit-logs-to-enduse

Comment: @Manu Yeah, it's ongoing. I also expect this feature.